# A nice way to phrase this theorem about ideals in Noetherian rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

I came across this theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $I$ be an ideal of a Noetherian ring $R$. Then there is $r \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\operatorname{rad}(I)^r \subseteq I$.

Is there a concise way to state this in term of primary or nil ideals?
At first I tried comparing this with the assertion "$\operatorname{rad}(I)/I$ is a nil ideal of $R/I$", but the latter only says that whenever $x \in \operatorname{rad}(I)$, there is $r \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x^r \in I$. So it's a weaker assertion for two reasons: one, in the theorem $r$ is not allowed to depend on $x$, and two, the theorem says that any product $x_1 \ldots x_r$ is in $I$, not just elements of the form $x^r$.

Comment: A nil ideal is one whose elements are nilpotent, which I strictly weaker than what you’re describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that ‘ $\operatorname{rad}I/I$ is *nilpotent* in $R/I$ (or the radical of $R/I$ is nilpotent).